# Why isn’t the text-shadow CSS property working here?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to apply a nice text shadow to two words, but it seems that the CSS isn’t doing anything. See [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jct0vf0z/).

```
<p id="np">Nakshatro Production</p>
```

```css
#np {
    text-shadow: -0px 0px 1px 0 hsl(20, 100%, 16%),
                 -2px 2px 2px -1px hsl(20, 100%, 14%),
                 -4px 4px 2px -2px hsl(20, 100%, 12%),
                 -6px 6px 3px -3px hsl(20, 100%, 10%),
                 -8px 8px 2px -4px hsl(20, 100%, 8%),
                 -10px 10px 2px -5px hsl(20, 100%, 6%);
}
```

Comment: Which browser are you using?

Comment: google chrome i am using

Comment: text-shadow takes 3 values unlike box-shadow, i believe only IE would accept a fourth

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/jct0vf0z/2/

Comment: In the future, troubleshooting can be made easier by using the Chrome dev tools. Right click on the element, click inspect element, find the offending CSS under styles, and double click to edit and see what works and what doesn't.

Answer (score 2):

Unlike `box-shadow`, `text-shadow` doesn’t support a spread value; you can only select offset and blur. That is, use a maximum of three size values and one colour. [jsFiddle, not quite the same.](http://jsfiddle.net/jct0vf0z/3/)

Answer (score 0):

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_text-shadow.asp. You have given an extra data which is not accepted.

```
#np{

text-shadow: -12px 2px 2px hsl(120,70%,50%),
     2px 12px 2px hsl(120,30%,20%),
      -2px 2px 12px  hsl(120,100%,50%);  
}
```

Try this and I think you will have some idea.

ALso modified ur fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/jct0vf0z/4/